# Run select shell commands as root without giving the user sudo permisions?

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to run three separate nmcli commands

```
nmcli connection down config-AP

nmcli connection up config-AP

nmcli device wifi hotspot con-name config-AP ssid device band bg password password
```

If these aren't called as root they timeout

```
Error: Timeout 10 sec expired.
```

How can I allow these commands to run without adding a user to the sudoers file?

Comment: You do know that you don't need to allow unlimited access through `sudo`, but that you can list the programs a user is allowed to run with raised privilege? So the question is, if you have some other reason to avoid using `sudo`?

Comment: @ilkkachu How is that done?

Comment: @foki, you list the allowed commands in the `/etc/sudoers` config file. Like `ilkkachu ALL = /bin/dmesg` or so. See the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html), it has examples. Or look for tutorials online, there are probably better ones than any I could write.

Comment: @ilkkachu Correct. However, that doesn't really look like an elegant solution to what OP wants. `nmcli` is an umbrella program that may use multiple other tools. For example, if it's a VPN, it might use `openconnect`, which in turn calls `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script`, which then calls `reslvconf` and many others, etc... Exploring source code of a program and adding all programs that may be used doesn't look too practical.

Comment: @foki, re. it being an umbrella program, I fail to see an issue with that. Anyway, I'm not sure how useful it is to make guesses on the wants and needs of a five-year-old post. Re. that "Correct.", if you're asking just to test if I know something, don't. Just post an answer of your own, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a command that can do no harm but needs root privileges you can change it to have "set user id" (set uid or suid) attribute.  Here is an example:

```
ls -l /bin/chsh
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 23376 Mar 22 21:23 /bin/chsh*
```

This file has the "s" tag to show that during execution it will assume the `root` (3rd column) user id.

However, this is potentially dangerous and a local attacker able to call that command could overtake your system if the command itself is not programmed to handle being called suid 0. You have been warned.

Having said this, you could do:

```
chmod u+s,a-w /usr/bin/nmcli
```

(please change the path if necessary, e.g. to `/bin/nmcli` according to your system)

If you wish to restrict the people being able to call the (now dangerous) command you could make it accessible only to a special group, e.g. by

```
chgrp john /usr/bin/nmcli
chmod o= /usr/bin/nmcli
```

That way, only someone in the group `john` (and root) could call the command. Use a group only your user is in, ideally.

Comment: I should probably add that during a system update to that command the new attributes could be reset to default values. You can make them permanent on some systems but the way to do it varies. In openSUSE, for instance, this used to be done by creating `/etc/permissions.local` with an appropriate entry. (You could also call the commands again after an update to that file, it does not happen that often.)

Comment: This is very unlikely to solve your problem. `nmcli` calls `resolveconf`. If you don't set `s` bit on `resolvconf`, then `nmcli` is useless. Otherwise, if you also set the `s` bit on `resolveconf` you're at a HUGE security risk.

Comment: @foki If a root process creates a child process like `resolveconf` won't that also run as EUID 0?